# Conexion entre AndroidStudio y Arduino UNO

Tags: java, android-studio, arduino

Estoy desarrollando una app la cual envia datos hacia Firebase y ahora necesito implementar un boton (fisico) el cual se encuentra conectado via bluetooth mediante  una plataforma de arduino UNO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ademas anexo parte del codigo donde tengo la conexión

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button IdEncender_Aux,IdApagar,IdDesconectar_01;
    TextView IdControl_01,IdBufferIn_01;
    //---//
    Handler bluetoothIn;
    final int handlerState = 0;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private StringBuilder DataStringIN = new StringBuilder();
    private ConnectedThread MyConexionBT;


    // Identificador unico de servicio - SPP UUID
    private static final UUID BTMODULEUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // String para la direccion MAC
    private static String address = null;
    //---//

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        IdEncender_Aux = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdEncender);
        IdApagar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdApagar);
        IdDesconectar_01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.IdDesconectar);

        IdControl_01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IdControl);
        IdBufferIn_01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IdBufferIn);


        bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == handlerState) {
                    String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;
                    DataStringIN.append(readMessage);

                    int endOfLineIndex = DataStringIN.indexOf("#");

                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {
                        String dataInPrint = DataStringIN.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);
                        IdBufferIn_01.setText("Dato: " + dataInPrint); //<-<- PARTE A MODIFICAR >->->
                        DataStringIN.delete(0, DataStringIN.length());
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); // get Bluetooth adapter
        VerificarEstadoBT();

        // Configuracion onClick listeners para los botones
        // para indicar que se realizara cuando se detecte
        // el evento de Click
        IdEncender_Aux.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyConexionBT.write("1");
            }
        });
        IdApagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyConexionBT.write("0");
            }
        });

        IdDesconectar_01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (btSocket!=null)
                {
                    try {btSocket.close();}
                    catch (IOException e)
                    { Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;}
                }
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException
    {
        //crea un conexion de salida segura para el dispositivo
        //usando el servicio UUID
        return device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(BTMODULEUUID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //Consigue la direccion MAC desde DeviceListActivity via intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        //Consigue la direccion MAC desde DeviceListActivity via EXTRA
        address = intent.getStringExtra(Main2Activity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);    //<-<- PARTE A MODIFICAR >->->

        //Setea la direccion MAC
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        try
        {
            btSocket = createBluetoothSocket(device);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La creacción del Socket fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Establece la conexión con el socket Bluetooth.
        try
        {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {}
        }
        MyConexionBT = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        MyConexionBT.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        try
        { // Cuando se sale de la aplicación esta parte permite
            // que no se deje abierto el socket
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {}
    }

    //Comprueba que el dispositivo Bluetooth Bluetooth está disponible y solicita que se active si está desactivado
    private void VerificarEstadoBT() {

        if(btAdapter==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "El dispositivo no soporta bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //Crea la clase que permite crear el evento de conexion
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;
            try
            {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Se mantiene en modo escucha para determinar el ingreso de datos
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Envia los datos obtenidos hacia el evento via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                    Log.d("mensaje: ",readMessage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //Envio de trama
        public void write(String input)
        {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(input.getBytes());
                Log.d("mensaje_02: ",input);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //si no es posible enviar datos se cierra la conexión
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La Conexión fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
        public void read(String i){
            try {
                mmInStream.read(i.getBytes());
                Log.d("mensaje_01: ",i);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //si no es posible enviar datos se cierra la conexión
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "La Conexión fallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`
 no consigo aun resolver mi problema que consiste en enviar una señal a la app por medio del boton bluetooth, actualmente lo tengo conectado como se ve en la imagen

Agradezco de antemano cualquier recomendacion o ayuda con el codigo y  la conexion

Estoy Usando:

Modulo de bluetooth hc 05 con pulsador
Arduino Genuino UNO
Android Studio 3.4